# GAS importHtml not updating or emailing correctly when spreadsheet not active using time trigger

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I am using an importHtml command to bring in barometric pressure data to a spreadsheet.  Then, I have it email me if the barometric pressure gets higher or lower than a certain values.  This works great when I run the script with everything open.  However, I've tried having a time trigger check it every four hours, but then the variables don't seem to grab the right info.

An email when it works right says, "This is just a test. The loop variable ended as 1 and the current pressure is 29.73".

An email when it doesn't work right says, "This is just a test. The loop variable ended as 16 and the current pressure is #N/A".

Here is the code:

```
function checkPressure() {

  // Get the data from the "Chart Data" sheet.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Ah2VsNnRu1aWdEFkWGtTQklqTTd6bVY4UW8yQ1F3TWc");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Chart Data");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,16,4);
  var dataBp = dataRange.getValues();
  Browser.msgBox(dataBp);

  // Initialize variables/constants

  var highPressure = false;
  var lowPressure = false;
  var highBpLimit = 30.01;
  var lowBpLimit = 29.99;
  var i = 0;
  var headers = ("Date", "Time", "Date/Time", "Pressure");
  var myEmail = "MYEMAILHERE";

  while (!highPressure && !lowPressure && i < dataBp.length) {
    if (dataBp[i][3] > highBpLimit) {
      highPressure = true;
      var highBpReading = dataBp[i][3];
      var highBpDate = dataBp[i][0];
      var highBpTime = dataBp[i][1];
    }
    if (dataBp[i][3] < lowBpLimit) {
      lowPressure = true;
      var lowBpReading = dataBp[i][3];
      var lowBpDate = dataBp[i][0];
      var lowBpTime = dataBp[i][1];
    }
    i++;
  }
   if (highPressure) {
    var message = "There is a barometric pressure of " + highBpReading + " at " + highBpTime + " on the date of " + highBpDate;
    MailApp.sendEmail(myEmail, "High BP Warning", message);
  }
    if (lowPressure) {
    var message = "There is a barometric pressure of " + lowBpReading + " at " + lowBpTime + " on the date of " + lowBpDate;
    MailApp.sendEmail(myEmail, "Low BP Warning", message);
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(myEmail,"Test BP Warning", "This is just a test. The loop variable ended as " + i + " and the current pressure is " + dataBp[0][3]);
}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, would be good to get some feedback on this. One can only assume that the OpenById call doesn't actually trigger the importhtml calls to refresh. Is pretty frustrating.